# Continuous subsection

Tags: counters, subsection

In Latex pls

```
hello I need the sections and subsections to look like this:

I. first section
   1. first subsection
   2. second subsection

II. second section
   3. third subsection


also I need that all theorems and lemma are counted as follows:

1. first subsection
   lemma 1.1 
   theorem 1.2 
2. second subsection
   theorem 2.1
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}[subsection]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[subsection]
\newtheorem{kor}{Korollar}[subsection]

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\section{Poisson-Equation}
\subsection{Harmonic functions}
...
\subsection{Poisson formula}
...
```

Comment: Please make your requirement more clearly and provide the corresponding MWE.

Comment: Ok I'll try. What is MWE?

Comment: Probably you want something like `\counterwithout{subsection}{section}`, but it is hard to tell since you question is unclear

Comment: @Nikare MWE: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Thanks Michael this solves my first request! Now I just need the counting for the thorems

Comment: after declaring `satz` use `\newtheorem{lem}[satz]{Lemma}` not `\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[subsection]` so they use the same counter

Comment: @david nice it worked! But why? I don't get the rule behind it.

Comment: your form is allocating a new counter for each theorem type, resetting to 1 on each subsection. My form does that for satz  but for `lem`, with optional argument _first_ , means "use same counter as `satz`" so they are numbered in the same sequence.

Comment: I am confused here. There is indentation before subsections in the first group, which is missing in the second group (with theorems). Does it mean theorems should have extra indentation?

Comment: @Celdor ignore the ascii-art and just look at the numbering:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied custom styles due to indentation and custom numbering. Also, I found a hack to remove the last punctuation, which by default follows a theorem number. Below is the outcome

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

%%% Sections
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\counterwithout*{subsection}{section}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\hspace{15pt}\arabic{subsection}.}

%%% Lemma and theorem
% Custom styles
\newtheoremstyle{indplain}{3pt}{3pt}{\itshape}{\parindent}{\bfseries}{}{.5em}{}
\newtheoremstyle{inddef}{3pt}{3pt}{}{\parindent}{\bfseries}{}{.5em}{}
% Apply custom styles
\theoremstyle{indplain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\theoremstyle{inddef}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
% Format counters
\renewcommand*{\thelemma}{\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{lemma}}
\renewcommand*{\thetheorem}{\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{theorem}}
\makeatletter
  % Remove the the full stop after the theorem number
  \patchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\kant[1][1]\kant[2][1]
\begin{theorem}\kant[4][1]\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}\kant[3][1]\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}\kant[4][1]\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}\kant[3][1]\end{lemma}

\subsection{Second subsection}
\begin{lemma}\kant[3][1]\end{lemma}

\section{Second section}
\subsection{Third subsection}
\kant[1][1]
\begin{theorem}\kant[4][1]\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}\kant[3][1]\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP wants thorems, lemmas to be numbered in same sequence

Comment: It's corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your time. This is what I wanted thx. :)